# java: extract string from input using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to parse the input with condition:

- find `<AD(1 to n)>` and
- get the string within `<AD> to </AD>`

Below is my code and input text. But, I am not getting expected output. 
The output I am getting is as below,

`[T, > Primary , ddress , /, T, >, > Primary , ddress Line ,  ~Primary , ddress Line ,  ~Primary , ddress Line , ~Primary , ddress Line , ~City~State~Zip Code~Country, /, >;
, T, > Office , ddress , /, T, >, > Primary , ddress Line ,  ~Primary , ddress Line ,  ~Primary , ddress Line , ~Primary , ddress Line , ~City~State~Zip Code~Country, /, >;
, T, > Home , ddress , /, T, >, > Primary , ddress Line ,  ~Primary , ddress Line ,  ~Primary , ddress Line , ~Primary , ddress Line , ~City~State~Zip Code~Country, /, >]`

```
public class TestProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String address ="<AT1> Primary Address </AT1><AD1> Primary Address Line 1 ~Primary Address Line 2 ~Primary Address Line 3~Primary Address Line 4~City~State~Zip Code~Country</AD1>;\n"
                + "<AT2> Office Address </AT2><AD2> Primary Address Line 1 ~Primary Address Line 2 ~Primary Address Line 3~Primary Address Line 4~City~State~Zip Code~Country</AD2>;\n"
                + "<AT3> Home Address </AT3><AD2> Primary Address Line 1 ~Primary Address Line 2 ~Primary Address Line 3~Primary Address Line 4~City~State~Zip Code~Country</AD2>";

        System.out.println(captureValues(address));
    }

    public static Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("[^<AD0-9]+");

    public static List<String> captureValues(String address)
    {
        Matcher mtch = ptn.matcher(address);
        List<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(mtch.find())
        {
            ips.add(mtch.group());
        }
        return ips;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex might be not the best tool for that, but with given input try:

```
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("(?<=<AD(\\d)>).+?(?=</AD\\d>)");
```

which means:

- `(?<=<AD(\\d)>)` - positive loohbehind for `<AD(digit)>`,
- `.+?` - one or more of any characters, but with lazy quantifier, so it will match minimum quantitiy of characters to make whole regex to match,
- `(?=</AD\\d>)` - positive lookahead for `</AD(digit)>`

the first digit is in capturing groups `(\\d)`, so you can still get it by `mtch.group(1)` method. If you don't need it you can remove parentheses.

Your regex `[^<AD0-9]+` means one or more of any character but not: digit(`0-9`), `<`, `A` or `D`, this is why you get invalid output, it cut your input in every place where regex doesn't match.